# Serial POSIX write to the file descriptor at some point seems to halt the program

Tags: c, serial-port, posix, message-queue

I have two different programs where one writes to a message queue via `mq_send` while the other consumes it via `mq_receive`.

One issue I'm running into is serial write in the `Consumer` thread seems to cause a hang after some time of writing to a serial port.

The consumer thread was able to receive 51 times before it seems to get hung. When I comment out the serial write part, the program runs fine without any interruption.

Interestingly, I was able to receive more or less messages after modifying `MAX_MSG_SIZE` value. Also, the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_getattr.3.html) only talks about the receive buffer size being greater than `mq_msgsize`.

Does that mean the serial port is getting clogged somehow particularly if the receiver end of the serial port isn't reading the data?

I don't see any errors from any of the functions.

In the actual code, the producer writes to the message queue based on certain intervals defined in the timer and there are overlapping periods where messages are written with really close priximity.

```c
// common.h

#define MAX_MESSAGES                            10
#define MAX_MSG_SIZE                            72
#define MSG_BUFFER_SIZE                         MAX_MSG_SIZE + 10
#define QUEUE_PERMISSIONS                       0660

#define COMMON_QUEUE                            "/MSG_QUEUE"

typedef enum
{
    LEFT,
    RIGHT
} CmdType;

typedef struct
{
    CmdType cmd;
    uint16_t length;
    uint8_t payload[64];
} Pkt;
```

**Consumer**

```c
#include "common.h"

int fd;  // file descriptor for serial port

static struct mq_attr attr = {.mq_flags = 0, .mq_maxmsg = MAX_MESSAGES, .mq_msgsize = MAX_MSG_SIZE, .mq_curmsgs = 0};

void *Consumer(void *args)
{   
    uint8_t rcvBuffer[MSG_BUFFER_SIZE];
    mqd_t *mqd = (mqd_t *) args;
    int ret;

    while(1)
    {   
        ret = mq_receive(*mqd, rcvBuffer, sizeof(rcvBuffer), 0);
        if (ret == -1)
        {
            perror ("mq_receive failed");
        }
        printf ("Received data: %d\n", *rcvBuffer);

        // serial write 
        int sizeWritten = write(fd, rcvBuffer, sizeof(rcvBuffer));
        if (sizeWritten < 0)
        { 
            perror ("Write to serial failed");
        }
    }
}

int UartInit()
{
    fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB4", O_RDWR); 

    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror ("Serial port failed to open");
        return -1;
    }

    if(tcgetattr(fd, &tty) != 0)    
    {
      perror("Error from tcgetattr");
      return -1;
    }

    cfsetspeed(tty, B115200);     // baud rate to 115200

    tty->c_cflag |= CS8;

    tty->c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;

    tty->c_cflag |= CRTSCTS;       // HW flow control

    tty->c_cflag &= ~PARENB;

    tty.c_iflag |= ICRNL;                // enable translating carriage return to newline on input
    tty.c_iflag |= IGNBRK;               // ignore break condition
    tty.c_iflag &= ~BRKINT;
    tty.c_iflag &= ~INPCK;               // disable input parity check
    tty.c_iflag &= ~PARMRK;             // ignore input bytes with parity or framing errors are marked when passed to the program
    tty.c_iflag &= ~ISTRIP;             // ignore stripping off the 8th bit
    
    tty.c_oflag |= OCRNL;              // Map CR to NL on output.
    tty.c_oflag |= ONLCR;             // Map NL to CR-NL on output.
    tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;             // Disable implementation-defined output processing
    
    tty.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;            // Disable canonical mode
    tty.c_lflag &= ~ISIG;
    tty.c_lflag &= ~IEXTEN;            // Disable implementation-defined input processing
    tty.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO|ECHOE|ECHOK|ECHONL|ECHOCTL|ECHOPRT|ECHOKE);
    
    // settimg serial read blocking behavior
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 0; 
   
    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0)
    {
        printf("Error %i from tcsetattr: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    return 1
}

int main() 
{
    mqd_t mqd;
    
    int ret = UartInit(); 
    
    if ((mqd = mq_open(COMMON_QUEUE, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, QUEUE_PERMISSIONS, &attr)) == -1) 
    {
        perror ("Message queue failed to instantiate");
        return -1;
    }
        
    if (pthread_create(&consumerTd, NULL, Consumer, (void *) &mqd) != 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    
    pthread_join(consumerTd, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks like it's enabling flow control on the serial port.  If the other end of the connection hasn't indicated that it's ready to accept data, your serial port won't transmit anything.  You'll slowly fill up your serial port's transmit buffer and once there's no more space to buffer data, attempting to write more data will either block and wait for space or return an error (in your case, it's the former).

I recommend checking to make sure that *both* sides of the connection are using the same flow control settings, that your serial cable actually has the flow control pins wired through (many inexpensive ones only wire up the TX/RX/GND lines), and that your serial port supports hardware flow control (USB-to-serial adapters frequently do not).  Disabling flow control would avoid the hangup, but you might transmit data when the other side isn't ready to receive it.

Comment: Thanks. But if HW flow control is disabled on the receiver end, shouldnt I not be receiving messages? I’ll check on the receiver end but curious still about the possibility of reception of messages just fine

Comment: @xyf If the other side doesn't have flow control enabled, it will transmit messages whenever it wants. As long as your side is ready to receive a message, you'll receive it.  The problems occur when your side *isn't* ready (transmitter would send anyway and you miss the message), or if you were waiting for the other side to indicate that it was "ready to receive" (that signal isn't supported so it won't ever get set).